# OTRS invoker remote webservice not running resend request again

Tags: java, web-services, rest, otrs

I configured invoker to make webservice request when ticket is changed or updated.
it working fine.
If the ticket changed and the remote webservice is not running than it will wait till timeout happen and after that it wont make another request.

Now one requirement i got is when ticket is changed the invoker will make a call to remote host url, if that remote webservice is not running than after timeout happens i have to make another request to webservice till remote webservice gets the request.

how can i configure the invoker to resend the request to the remote webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with the Generic Interface for quite some time and in my experience you can't configure it to behave like this.

**You can however create your own solution:**

You could add a dynamic field for all tickets of type checkbox, let's call it `WebserviceUnavailable` and set it to `False`/`Invalid` by default. In your invoker the first thing you do is set that dynamic field `WebserviceUnavailable` to `True`. Then you do your processing and prepare your data for the Generic Interface as usual. In the code for the response you set the dynamic field `WebserviceUnavailable` to `False` if your processing went well.

Then you can write another script that gets called periodically (using a Cronjob for example). In this script you search for all tickets that have the `Webserviceunavailable` dynamic field with the value `True`. For each of those tickets you call your webservice again.